# How to convert a CSS and a javascript to a class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have some problems converting the CSS id to a class and the javascript to match it. I need to use the script multiple times on the site

Here my code:
CSS:

```
#first {
    background-color: #FFF;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
var divh = document.getElementById('first').offsetHeight;

//keep default height
var divh = $("#first").outerHeight();

document.getElementById("first").style.height = "100px";

//toggle functions
$('div:first').toggle(
  function () {
     $("#first").stop().animate({
        height: divh +'px'
     }, 1000);
  },
  function () {
    $("#first").stop().animate({
      height: '100px'
    }, 1000);
  }
)
```

Comment: What do you want it to do, and what is the (presumably wrong) result you're getting?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you can just do:

```
.first {
    background-color: #FFF;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

And the Javascript would be something like this:

```
var divh = $('.first').offsetHeight;

//keep default height
var divh = $(".first").outerHeight();

$('.first').style.height = "100px";

//toggle functions
$('div:first').toggle(
  function () {
     $(".first").stop().animate({
        height: divh +'px'
     }, 1000);
  },
  function () {
    $(".first").stop().animate({
      height: '100px'
    }, 1000);
  }
)
```

Just uses the jQuery selector to select the class instead of the ID.

Comment: What exactly "doesn't work"? Have you tried running in Firefox using Firebug, it will show you any Javascript errors.

Comment: The slide does not animate anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use a "[class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)" to get all the elements belonging to that class and then apply animation to all of them or one by one by using the `each` function (see [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)). Something like:

CSS

```
.first {
background-color: #FFF;
width: auto;
height: auto;
overflow: hidden;
padding: 10px;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$('.first').each(function () {
    var divh = $(this).outerHeight();
    ecc. ecc.
})
```

Comment: If you call the toggle() function (or any other function for that matter) using the class selector it will be applied to all elements matching that class.

Answer (score 0):

use **.first** instant of #first

Answer (score 0):

Mark's answer is almost entirely correct.

Although, he changed $('div:first') to $('div.first') which are not the same thing.

:first is part of jQuery selectors to select only the first matched element (see [here](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/)).

So, if you want to pick the first div, use $('div:first'). If you want to select all divs with the "first" class, use $('div.first').